# How to use function from NPM library in html.eex template

Tags: javascript, webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework

Using Phoenix 1.4 with webpack, I added `"findandreplacedomtext": "^0.4.6"` to my package.json file and installed the library.

Now in app.js I have `import findAndReplaceDOMText from 'findandreplacedomtext';` and that allows me to use the library, **but it only works within the app.js file**. I want to be able to use the library in my view templates but whenever I try to use it in a template, I get an error in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: findAndReplaceDOMText is not defined`.

This is what the code looks like inside of my template:

```
<div id="container">
  This is a test.
</div>
<script>
  findAndReplaceDOMText(document.getElementById('container'), {
    find: 'test',
    wrap: 'mark'
  });
</script>
```

That throws an error in the console. But if I put the same javascript code in app.js below the library's import statement it works. How can I use the library inside of my view template and outside of app.js?

Comment: Try this: In app.js add ‘window.findAndReplaceDOMText = findAndReplaceDOMText ‘ after importing the module. This exposes the module outside of app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of webpack.config.js I put `const webpack = require('webpack');` so that in the plugins list I could put `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({findAndReplaceDOMText: "findandreplacedomtext"})`. This made it so that I could remove the import statement for the library from app.js.

Then, in app.js I put `window.findAndReplaceDOMText = findAndReplaceDOMText;` in order to expose the module outside of app.js.

Finally, in my template, I had to wrap the function in a content loaded event in order to make sure I wasn't invoking the function before it was loaded.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    findAndReplaceDOMText(document.getElementById('container'), {
      find: 'test',
      wrap: 'mark'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your js, you're selecting an element by id 'container' but it's a class, so it should be:

```
findAndReplaceDOMText(document.getElementsByClassName('container')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but it was an error in the question, I've fixed it but still have the problem.